Finite Difference Modeling of MOSFET Device
Does anyone know of any references for MOSFET modeling done using the Finite Difference Method that they could point me to?  I understand the gist of the operation, namely using Poisson's equation to solve for the potential, using the potential to solve for the carrier concentration, using the continuity equations to solve for current (carrier flow), and then plugging this back into Poisson's equation, but I have a number of questions about how the implementation is actually done that would benefit from seeing a worked example. What I am ultimately wanting to do is calculate the drain current as a function of gate and drain voltage. Something that in theory should be straightforward but is proving difficult.

Generically: discretize your system of equations then plug it into a computer. More could be said with more details (actual ODE/PDEs, boundaries, etc).

It's not just difficult in theory. If you buy a batch of the same MOSFET device you will find a considerable variation of threshold voltages and saturation currents between different devices. That kind of tells you that the physics is sensitive to the device geometry (probably even at the level of single atomic layers), doping concentrations etc. (but I have never seen a statistical analysis regarding the sensitivities). This probably indicates that a numerical simulation won't do much good, either, since you don't know the actual physical parameters with enough precision.

@KyleKanos I understand that portion, my confusion is how I implement the boundary conditions, and how I actually calculate the current. Also that I have 2 matrices, potential and concentration, but 3 equations to update (how exactly do I implement the continuity equation in a steady state model?).

@Schoppe there are textbooks available that discuss how to implement FDM for a variety of scenarios. It would be beneficial for you to peruse it.

@KyleKanos can you suggestion one perhaps?
